# Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined - For nodes but sibling nodes do not error

Tags: javascript, ajax, nodes

I have an Ajax application from which I am creating a table from afterwards. I get a response back as expected in full which I can see in chrome Network tab and also testing in SoapUI.

When i create my table however it keeps throwing the error "Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined" when i reference 2 particular elements even though I can see a response and value for them in the Network tab.

```
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Product Type</th><th>Value(£)</th><th>Install Type(£)</th><th>ID</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("productInfo");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += `<tr><td>
      ${x[i].getElementsByTagName("productName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue}
    </td><td>
      ${x[i].getElementsByTagName("value")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue}
    </td><td>
      ${x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue}
    </td><td>
      ${x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue}
    </td></tr>`;
  }
)
```

When I try to use the data from the tag name "value" or "name" I receive the error but none of the other sibling nodes have this issue.

I can't seem to make sense of why that is happening as they nodes exist and are children of the initial "productInfo" element

Comment: It's hard to help with an answer without seeing the value of xmlDoc, could you add in the response value?

Comment: <productInfo>
        <id>156531736</id>
        <productName>Ethernet Everywhere™</productName>
        <value>327.7</value>
        <name>2917.0</name>
        <status>OK</status>
      </productInfo>

Comment: the above is the xml response that im working with in this instance

Comment: That makes sense, how are you creating the xml that is getting passed in? That is the only thing I can think may be different because everything else looks fine.

Comment: I am using a http post request to create a soap call for the xml. I have also written a function to check the child nodes of 'productInfo' to sure and they display as being